# Sequential Bayesian updating with binary data (in a case where a beta-bernoulli setup seems inappropriate)

Tags: time-series, bayesian, modeling, binary-data, conjugate-prior

An unknown parameter $\theta$ is randomly drawn at time $t=0$ according to *prior* p.d.f. $\mu_0(\cdot)$ that has support $[L,R]\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.

At each time $t\in\{1,2,...\}$ an agent makes an *estimate* $a_t\in\mathbb{R}$ of $\theta$ and observes an *outcome* $y_t\,|\,(a_t,\theta) \sim\text{Bernoulli}(\sigma(a_t,\theta))$, where $\sigma:\mathbb{R}^2\to[0,1]$ yields the probability of success given $(a_t,\theta)$. (Assume $y_t$ is independent of all draws $\{y_\tau\}_{\tau\neq t}$ and estimates $\{a_\tau\}_{t\neq t}$ from other periods.) Let $\mu_t(\cdot|a_1,y_1,...a_t,y_t)$ denote the posterior belief (formed using Bayes' rule) after observing the sequence $\{(\color{red}{a_\tau},\color{blue}{y_\tau})\}_{\tau=1}^t$ of $\color{red}{\text{estimates}}$ and $\color{blue}{\text{outcomes}}$.

**My (Soft) Question:** which $\mu_0$ and $\sigma$ would make analytically calculating posterior belief $\mu_t(\cdot|\cdot)$ tractable? [**Edit:** An example and a simpler question is found below. Many thanks to user [@Tim](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/35989/tim) for the great suggestion!]

**Small Request:** $\sigma$ could indeed be "anything," but ideally I would like something that is monotonically decreasing in how "far'' $a_t$ and $\omega$ are. (E.g. $\sigma(a_t,\theta)=\frac{1}{1+(a_t-\theta)^2}).$ To set ideas, I will now describe a class of functions that seems "reasonable" to me.

Let $\sigma(a_t,\theta)=h(\theta-a_t)$ where $h:R\to[0,1]$ satisfies

1. $h(0)=1>\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}}$ and
2. $h(x)=h(-x) \text{ and } h'(x)= -h'(-x) \ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

(i.e. unimodal and symmetric about $x=0$, where it achieves a maximum value of $1$).

---

$\textbf{Example:}$ Suppose a $\text{Uniform}([0,1])$ ($\equiv \text{Beta}(1,1)$) prior $\mu_0(\hat{\theta}):= \mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(\hat{\theta})$ and $\sigma(a_t,\theta):=\frac{1}{1+(a_t-\theta)^2 k}$, where $k>0$ is a *known* constant. Then, given $\theta$ and the first estimate $a_1$, the first outcome $y_1$ has a $\text{Bernoulli}\left([{1+(a_t-\theta)^2 k}]^{-1}\right)$ distribution. After making estimate $a_1\in\mathbb{R}$ and observing outcome $y_1\in\{0,1\}$, the agent forms posterior belief

\begin{equation}
\mu_1(\theta|a_1,y_1) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1-[1+(a_1-\theta)^2 k]^{-1}}{1-\int_{0}^{1} [1+(a_1-\hat{\theta})^2 k]^{-1} d\hat{\theta}}\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(\theta) &, \text{if } y_1 = 0\\
\frac{[1+(a_1-\theta)^2 k]^{-1}}{\int_{0}^{1} [1+(a_1-\hat{\theta})^2 k]^{-1} d\hat{\theta}}\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(\theta) &, \text{if } y_1 = 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where the above follows from Bayes' rule (after some cancellations and simplifications). Focusing on the $y=1$ case is sufficient for demonstrating that the resultant posterior belief is not a $\text{Beta}(\cdot,\cdot)$ distribution. Simplifying yields
\begin{equation}
\mu_1(\theta|a_1,y_1) = \frac{\sqrt{k}}{1+(\theta-x)^2} \frac{\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(\theta)}{\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{k}}{1-(k)(1-a_1)(a_1)}\right)}.
\end{equation}
I don't think I made an error in my derivation. The above is quite complicated, and I am afraid will get more complicated in $t>1$.

At the root of these complications is $\sigma(\cdot,\cdot)$, so I suppose my question should focus on that.

**Simplified Question:** assuming a $\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$, prior which choice of $\sigma(\cdot)$ guarantees that the posterior is also $\text{Beta}(\cdot,\cdot)$? (Feel free to assume $\alpha=1=\beta$, i.e. $\text{Uniform}([0,1])$).

---

Comment: You made it very abstract, could you give us an actual example of the data you have and the model you have in mind? Why it cant be beta-Bernoulli?

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you so much for taking the time to think about my question. That is a very good suggestion; I provided an example above that hopefully clarifies my problem. 

Regarding the data: this is actually for a theoretical model, similar to a [Bandit problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit), so I don't have any *actual* (real world) data! The ``data' ({(*a*ₜ,*y*ₜ)}ₜ₌₁,₂,...)' are [*endogenously*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exogenous_and_endogenous_variables) produced by the agent in the model (at each *t* chooses an *a*ₜ, which affects the distribution of *y*ₜ).

Comment: I understand that my question has aspects that may be outside the specialization of many stats stackexchange denizens, but my question really does boil down to one about Bayes' rule and conjugate priors. I tried my best (via terminology, notation, etc.) to present my question in a "familiar" form, but still please do let me know if there is anything I can clarify. Any help I can get on this is deeply appreciated.